# How to select only one part of a Tensorflow dataset, and change the dimensions

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I wish to train my model on 10 frame segments of UCF101, without any label. Currently I have this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
x_train = tfds.load('ucf101', split='train', shuffle_files=True, batch_size = 64)
>>> print(x_train)
<_OptionsDataset shapes: {label: (None,), video: (None, None, 256, 256, 3)}, types: {label: tf.int64, video: tf.uint8}>
```

I would like the dimensions of the dataset to be (None, 10, 256, 256, 3), and not include the label.

Edit: I tried using lambda expressions in `.map()`, but this yielded an error.

```
new_x_train = x_train.map(lambda x: tf.py_function(func=lambda y: tf.convert_to_tensor(sample(y.numpy().tolist(), 10), dtype=uint8), inp=[x['video']], Tout=tf.uint8))
```

```
NameError: name 'sample' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this was simply to download the dataset files elsewhere, so I had a list of .avi files in my directory, and then preprocess these files outside of tensorflow. I used the cv2 library and the following code, where I borrowed the two functions from elsewhere:

```
# Utilities to open video files using CV2
def crop_center_square(frame):
  y, x = frame.shape[0:2]
  min_dim = min(y, x)
  start_x = (x // 2) - (min_dim // 2)
  start_y = (y // 2) - (min_dim // 2)
  return frame[start_y:start_y+min_dim,start_x:start_x+min_dim]

def load_video(path, max_frames=0, resize=(256, 256)):
  cap = cv2.VideoCapture(path)
  frames = []
  try:
    while True:
      ret, frame = cap.read()
      if not ret:
        break
      frame = crop_center_square(frame)
      frame = cv2.resize(frame, resize)
      frame = frame[:, :, [2, 1, 0]]
      frames.append(frame)

      if len(frames) == max_frames:
        break
  finally:
    cap.release()
  return np.array(frames) / 255.0


files = [f for f in glob.glob("**/*.avi", recursive=True)]

for video_path in files:
  video = load_video(video_path)
  video_name = video_path[video_path.find('/')+1:]
  num_frames = video.shape[0]
  print("Video in " + video_path + " has " + str(num_frames) + " frames.")
  for seg_num in range(math.floor(num_frames/10)):
    result = video[seg_num*10:(seg_num+1)*10, ...]
    new_filepath = video_name[:-4] + "_" + str(seg_num).zfill(2) + ".avi"
    print(new_filepath)
    out = cv2.VideoWriter(new_filepath,0, 25.0, (256,256))
    for frame_n in range(0,10):
      out.write(np.uint8(255*result[frame_n, ...]))
    out.release()
    del result
  del video
```

Answer (score 2):

Forgive me for the approximate answer, because I won't download the 6GB dataset to test my answer.

Why don't you just select the video when you iterate through the dataset:

```
next(iter(x_train))['video']
```

To select the dimensions, you can use normal `numpy` indexing. That would be an example with `mnist`:

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

data = tfds.load('mnist', split='train', batch_size=16)
```

```
<PrefetchDataset shapes: {image: (None, 28, 28, 1), 
    label: (None,)}, types: {image: tf.uint8, label: tf.int64}>
```

Now let's select only `image`, and select the first 10 observations.

```
dim = lambda x: x['image'][:10, ...]

next(iter(data.map(dim))).shape
```

```
TensorShape([10, 28, 28, 1])
```

See how I removed a `None` in the shape with simple indexing.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Don't hesitate to accept this solution or upvote it if it solved your problem. If that's not the case please let me know how I can improve it.

Comment: I'm just wondering where this goes in my code. It seems next(iter(data.map(dim))) is a single batch. How do I connect this to model.fit(x_train, ... ?

Comment: yes that's just one iteration so you see the resulting tensor. it goes nowhere. the changes should just be implemented as such: `data = data.map(dim)`

Comment: Nicolas, could you think of a way to do without discarding so much of the available dataset? Each video can have some hundreds of frames, and only taking [0:10] discards >90% of UCF101. Ideally one could take floor((number of frames)/10) ten-frame segments from each video.